# Embed full posts from Facebook (iFrame)

Tags: facebook

I would like to embed Facebook posts for a study that I'm conducting in Limesurvey using the iFrame option. 
The Facebook embedding-code works just fine, the only problem is that it doesn't show the full posts for posts consisting of long texts. You would have to click on "more" - but the problem is that you can then get redirected to the original post, which means that participants leave the survey.

Is there a way to change the parameters manually so that participants see the whole post?

Thanks!

Comment: Just tested with a longer post, clicking “more” just made the embed grow accordingly, but did not take me elsewhere …?

Comment: Just can say that it always redirects within Limesurvey. So the best way would be to embed the "whole" post.

Comment: Apart from the “show full post” checkbox in the generator, there isn’t anything more that you can specify in this regard.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Isn't it possible to build an individual iFrame where I can specify this?

Comment: No, that isn’t possible. If you use the URL of the plugin, then the functionality of cutting the text and what happens when users clicks more, is already baked in into that content; and if you used any other URL not intended for this, it most likely won’t allow displaying in frames on 3rd-party sites to begin with. The only thing you could to is get the data of the post via API, and then create your own view of it, but then all styling etc. would fall to you, and you most likely won’t be able to make it look 1:1 the same.