# Embed full posts from Facebook using Iframe

Tags: facebook, post, iframe, embed

I would like to embed Facebook posts for an ionic app I am creating using the iFrame option. The Facebook embedding-code works just fine, the only problem is that it doesn't show the full posts for posts consisting of long texts. You would have to click on "see more" - but the problem is that you can then get redirected to the original post, which means that users leave my app.

Is there a way to change the parameters manually?

Thanks!

Comment: All available parameters are listed in the documentation, and there isn’t one for what you want.

Comment: @CBroe It would help if you created an actual answer. "No, you can't do that", particularly with supporting documentation, is certainly an answer. You've basically answer this in a comment here, and also answered a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49384801) in comments a year and a half ago. If you posted an answer, we could close one of the questions as a duplicate of the other, which would certainly be considerably better than having two questions floating around that don't have an actual answer posted.